# Jquery UI - Tooltip is not working (showing blank)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

For some reason tooltip is working well on some pages but not the other. On this particular page it is showing as blank. I've also checked title attr without jquery tooltip and it is working fine. Any ideas?

**header.html**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    //initiate tabs jquery ui
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    //initiate tooltips
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

**content.html**

```
<td class="options-width">
            <div style="display: inline-block" title="Update">
                <a href="#"><span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span></a>
            </div> 
            <div style="display: inline-block" title="Clipboard">
                <a href="#"><span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-clipboard"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block" title="Delete">
                <a href="#"><span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-tag"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block" title="Tagged">
                <a href="#"><span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></a>
            </div>
</td>
```

**Output:**

[image: Tooltip is showing blank on some elements]

Comment: What version of JQuery and JQuery UI are you using? It works fine in a JSFiddle as-as: http://jsfiddle.net/JD8sA/

Comment: Jquery 1.9.1 and Jquery UI 1.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the tooltips are built when the document has finished loading, some dynamic content might not get them initialized.

Also make sure your all pages loads the jquery modules properly.

Comment: This is all static content and jquery modules are loaded, I've tested it with alert(), that was my first suspect.

Comment: Are the stylesheets included too?